# Template based XML to CSV conversion

Tags: c#, xml, linq, csv, xml-parsing

I am new to C# and I know this will be a very tough and challenging task for everyone. I have a case where I need to convert template based XML to CSV. I have listed the **Template, Sample XML and Expected CSV** below.

My Template will have some number of columns which should be the **headers** in output CSV. We want to match the each column from the Template with XML and check if it is present or not. If Template column value is present in XML the **add** it into the CSV and if not present then **add it as null** as given in below example.

Also in given XML example, it has three types of rows

1. TRX
2. TRXR
3. **TRXC**

We have to take only first two types of rows into consideration. We have to ignore the **TRXC** type rows from the XML.

> Given Template

```
var templeteList = new List<string> //Consider this as my template
        {
           "ID",
           "Name",
           "Address",
           "Phone",
           "Email",
           "Gender"     
        };
```

> Sample XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<StudentXML>
    <TRX ID="2" Name="Smita" Address="Pune" Gender="F" Phone="987654321"/>
    <TRX ID="2" Name="Ram"  Phone="3554321" Email="ram@mail.com" />
    <TRX ID="1" Name="John" Address="Mumbai" Phone="NULL" Email="John@mail.com" Gender="M" />
    <TRXR ID="3" Name="NULL" Address="Mumbai" Phone="121212" Email="Don@mail.com" Gender="M" />
    <TRXC ID="3" Name="Prem" Address="Mumbai" Phone="121212" Email="Prem@mail.com" Gender="M"/>
</StudentXML>
```

> Expected Output

```
"ID", "Name",   "Address",    "Phone",           "Email",          "Gender" 
"2",   "Smita",  "Pune",      "987654321",       "NULL",            "F"
"2",   "Ram",    "NULL",      "3554321",         "ram@mail.com",    "NULL"
"1",   "John",   "Mumbai",    "NULL",            "ohn@mail.com",    "M"
"3",   "NULL",   "Mumbai",    "121212",          "Don@mail.com",    "M"
```

I tried to use XML Reader, but it takes to much longer to convert XML to CSV for 0.6 million XML rows.

```
 var dataSet = new DataSet();
 dataSet.ReadXml("XML File Name");//This line takes to much longer
```

If anyone can help me out from here, I will be hearty thankful.

Comment: If the structure does not change I recommend `XmlSerializer` http://www.jonasjohn.de/snippets/csharp/xmlserializer-example.htm

Comment: @SebastianSchulz structure is getting changed and it will not be same for each row

Comment: You write: _We have to ignore the TRXC_. Next, you write the _Expected Output_ and there we see the data from **TRXC**. In what place a discrepancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the MemoryStream to write data from StreamWriter. Then read the MemoryStream using StreamReader as below,

```
            var templateList = new List<string> 
            {
               "ID",
               "Name",
               "Address",
               "Phone",
               "Email",
               "Gender"     
            };

            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("MyXMLFile.xml"))
            {
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (StreamWriter csvWriter = new StreamWriter(memoryStream))
                    {
                        csvWriter.WriteLine("\"" + string.Join("\",\"", templateList) + "\"");
                        xmlReader.MoveToContent();
                        while (xmlReader.Read())
                        {
                            if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element &&
                                (xmlReader.Name == "TRX" || xmlReader.Name == "TRXR"))
                            {
                                csvWriter.Write('"');

                                for (int i = 0; i < templateList.Count; i++)
                                {
                                    csvWriter.Write(xmlReader.MoveToAttribute(templateList[i]) ? xmlReader.Value.Replace(",", string.Empty) : null);

                                    if (i < templateList.Count - 1)
                                        csvWriter.Write("\",\"");
                                }
                                csvWriter.WriteLine('"');
                            }
                        }
                        csvWriter.Flush();
                        memoryStream.Position = 0;
                        using (StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(memoryStream))
                        {
                            while ((streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                            {
                                //Parse your csv line by line
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Linq to XML to get the info first and then process it to convert it in a csv as I show below:

```
XElement students= XElement.Load("YourXml.xml");
string csv =
    (from el in students.Elements()
     where el.Name!="TRXC"
     select
        String.Format("{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}",
            (string)el.Attribute("ID"),
            (string)el.Attribute("Name"),
            (string)el.Attribute("Address"),
            (string)el.Attribute("Phone"),
            (string)el.Attribute("Email"),
            (string)el.Attribute("Gender"),
            Environment.NewLine
        )
    )
    .Aggregate(
        new StringBuilder(),
        (sb, s) => sb.Append(s),
        sb => sb.ToString()
    );
 string header="ID,"+""+"Name,"+"Address,"+"Phone,"+"Email,"+"Gender,"+ Environment.NewLine;
 File.WriteAllText("yourCSV.csv", header+csv);
```

`StringBuilder` will help you to construct the result efficiently. If you try to concat element by element, you are going to create a new `string` every time you apply that operation which could affect your performance due to your amount of elements. I suggest you to read this [Jon Skeet's article](http://jonskeet.uk/csharp/stringbuilder.html) for more details

### Update 1

You can also do this to create your header:

```
var templeteList = new List<string> //Consider this as my template
        {
           "ID",
           "Name",
           "Address",
           "Phone",
           "Email",
           "Gender",
           Environment.NewLine    
        };
var header=String.Joing(",",templateList);
```

### Update 2

To do the same dynamically you will need to change a little bit my previous query:

```
var templeteList = new List<string> //Consider this as my template
        {
           "ID",
           "Name",
           "Address",
           "Phone",
           "Email",
           "Gender"     
        };
string csv =students.Elements()
                    .Where(el=>el.Name!="TRXC")
                    .Select(el=>{
                                  string result="";
                                  for(int i=0; i<templeteList.Count;i++)
                                  {
                                    result+=((string)el.Attribute(templateList[i])) +",";
                                  }
                                  result+= Environment.NewLine;
                                  return result;
                                })
                    .Aggregate(new StringBuilder(),
                               (sb, s) => sb.Append(s),
                                sb => sb.ToString()
                               );
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but unfortunately output does not contains headers as well as it returns only "ID" values and blank for all the remaining columns `2,,,,,,
2,,,,,,
1,,,,,,
3,,,,,,`

Comment: You are almost there but in above example you have hard coding the `String.Format` with `"{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}"` and also hard coded its attributes `(string)el.Attribute("ID"),  (string)el.Attribute("Name"),`. This should come from the templateList dynamically. It can be numbers of columns at run-time.

Comment: My friend, I think I taught you how to fish, with my solution you should be able to create what you need. Anyways I will try later ;)

Comment: As I mentioned in my question very first line **I am new to C#** and this is my learning curve.

Comment: @SmitaKoparkar, Here you go

Comment: Getting the error `An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred` on `result += (el.Attribute(templeteList[i]).Value) + ",";` line

Comment: Thanks again. This gives me perfect result. But unfortunately for 0.6 million rows, it gives error as `An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll`. :(

Answer (score 1):

`XmlReader` is the fastest way to parse XML. You have not shown your code using `XmlReader`, but you probably did something wrong. However, I can bet that this method is the fastest.

Try this code:

```
var templateList = new List<string> { "ID", "Name", "Address", "Phone", "Email", "Gender" };

using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
using (var csvWriter = new StreamWriter("test.csv"))
{
    csvWriter.WriteLine("\"" + string.Join("\",\"", templateList) + "\"");
    xmlReader.MoveToContent();

    while (xmlReader.Read())
    {
        if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element
            && xmlReader.Name != "TRXC")
        {
            csvWriter.Write('"');

            for (int i = 0; i < templateList.Count; i++)
            {
                if (xmlReader.MoveToAttribute(templateList[i]))
                    csvWriter.Write(xmlReader.Value);
                else
                    csvWriter.Write("NULL");

                if (i < templateList.Count - 1)
                    csvWriter.Write("\",\"");
            }
            csvWriter.WriteLine('"');
        }
    }
}
```

Test the code and report the results. If it's performance will be slow (sure?), we can try to speed it up with the use of `NameTable`.

---

What is your ultimate goal? It's weird: at first parse xml, creating a csv, then immediately parse the csv, creating something else.

OK, look this code:

```
IEnumerable<string[]> ParseXml()
{
    var templateList = new List<string> { "ID", "Name", "Address", "Phone", "Email", "Gender" };

    using (var xmlReader = XmlReader.Create("test.xml"))
    {
        yield return templateList.ToArray(); // header
        xmlReader.MoveToContent();

        while (xmlReader.Read())
        {
            if (xmlReader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element
                && xmlReader.Name != "TRXC") // exclude TRXC
            {
                string[] result = new string[templateList.Count];

                for (int i = 0; i < templateList.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (xmlReader.MoveToAttribute(templateList[i]))
                        result[i] = xmlReader.Value;
                    else
                        result[i] = "NULL";
                }
                yield return result; // each row
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Use:

```
foreach (string[] row in ParseXml())
{
    // process row
    // or
    foreach (string value in row)
    {
        // process value
    }
}
```

We do not create intermediate csv. We immediately process each string while xml parsing.

Comment: can we put the data into StreamReader instead of writing the file new file. I don't want to create seperate CSV file, I just want to convert it and read it line by line using StreamReader's Readline method?